# How to show a div when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a invisible `<div>` visible with a onChange event. But it is not working.

First I created a `<div>` where the user can select a option:

```
<div class="cusarea">
 <select class="form" name="cus_id" id="cus_id" onChange="getArea(this.value)" style="width: 100%;">
 <option selected disabled hidden value=""></option>
 <option value="1">1 | Name</option>
 <option value="2">2 | Name</option>
 <option value="3">3 | Name</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

After selecting a `<option>` the following `<div>` needs to appear:

```
<div id="cusinfoarea" style="display:none;">
 <label>Cus name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" width="100%" class="form" />
</div>
```

I am using the following javascript code for it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function getArea() {
  $('#cus_id').blur(function() {
   if($(this).val() != ""){
     $("#cusinfoarea").show();    
   }
  });

  $('#cus_id').focus(function() {
   $("#cusinfoarea").show();
  });   
 }
</script>
```

When I change the `<option>`, nothing is happening. Does anybody know what is wrong with my code?

Edit: I am trying to get a div visible after changing the option. Not to show div based on the selected value. I am not a JavaScript expert, but also the solution of the 'Show div based on select value' question is not working for me.

Comment: Why did you close my topic. The answer for the question "Show div based on select value " is not working for me

Comment: Try this:
 
`function getArea(val) {
  console.log(val);
  if(val != ""){
    $("#cusinfoarea").show();    
   }
}`

Comment: Ref: http://jsbin.com/loluweq/edit?html,js,console,output